# using a case expression inside select statement is fetching me wrong output. The output is a link attached

Tags: sql, case

```
case      
when SCHEDULES.START_DTTM - PATIENTS.DTTM_OF_BIRTH < 16 then  '" 1.C"'     
when  SCHEDULES.START_DTTM - PATIENTS.DTTM_OF_BIRTH >= 16 and SCHEDULES.START_DTTM - PATIENTS.DTTM_OF_BIRTH < 65 then   '"2.A"'  
ELSE      '"3.OP"'  
END AS AGEGROUP
```

[image]

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement.

Comment: Your condition based on day differences..?

Comment: Hi @jarlh 1.C is a string

Comment: @jarlh thats why >16 is with and condition <65

Comment: Oops... Didn't read carefully enough. But is that image showing the current result or the expected result?

Comment: @jarlh that is the current result but its not correct , if you examine the difference between the two dates the output age is displayed incorrect

Comment: How are we supposed to know what is *"wrong"* with the output, if you don't tell us which ones you think are wrong, and what you think they should be?

Comment: Try below query, Is it correct for expected output..?

Comment: @GarethD the difference between start date and date of birth say in the first row by year is <16 . So the output should be "1C". Like wise the output where the agegroup is OP the difference in age is between 16 to 65  hence that should be age group "1A".

Comment: What DMBS are you using? Screenshot looks like SQL Server management studion, but for clarity please tag your question with the appropriate tags.

Comment: In the first row the two dates are 19th March 2015 and 8th April, which are 20 days apart, so `"2.A"` seems correct to me.

Comment: @GarethD yes its SQL Server management studio , i will keep that in mind from next time

Comment: @GarethD its based upon year difference

Comment: This is exactly the kind of information that you need to include in your question in the first place, it shouldn't be up to other people to try and ask the right questions to extract the information from you. Something like "I am trying to return a value based on the number of years between two dates, but I am not getting the result I am expecting, in the first row the two dates are in the same year, but it is returning the value set for between 16 and 65 years". With this explanation it is immediately obvious what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how SQL Server deals with date arithmetic. Taking a single line:

```
SCHEDULES.START_DTTM - PATIENTS.DTTM_OF_BIRTH < 16
```

Since this expression uses multiple data types

```
(DATETIME) - (DATETIME) < (INT)
```

the first step is to convert them all into the same one. Since `DATETIME` has a [higher precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190309.aspx) than `INT` it is 16 that must be converted to a datetime:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, 16)
```

Gives:

```
1900-01-17 00:00:00.000
```

Now, if we simply use the result of your first row:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, '20150408 11:05') - CONVERT(DATETIME, '20150319');
```

We get a result of

```
1900-01-21 11:05:00.000
```

Which is `> 1900-01-17`, so the first expression in the case statement is false. For the next bit again, some conversion needs to be to convert 65 to a datetime (`1900-03-07`), since this is after `1900-01-21 11:05:00.000` the second expression evaluates to true, so `"2.A"` is returned.

Since you want to compare years, I think your case expression should be:

```
SELECT  START_DTTM,
        DTTM_OF_BIRTH,
        CASE WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, 16, DTTM_OF_BIRTH) > START_DTTM THEN '" 1.C"'  
            WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, 65, DTTM_OF_BIRTH) > START_DTTM THEN '"2.A"' 
            ELSE '"3.OP"'
        END AS AGEGROUP
FROM (VALUES
        (CONVERT(DATETIME, '20150408 11:05'), CONVERT(DATETIME, '20150319')),
        (CONVERT(DATETIME, '20150505 10:35'), CONVERT(DATETIME, '20150319')),
        (CONVERT(DATETIME, '20150323 11:47'), CONVERT(DATETIME, '20150319')),
        (CONVERT(DATETIME, '20150325 14:35'), CONVERT(DATETIME, '20150319')),
        (CONVERT(DATETIME, '20150320 18:00'), CONVERT(DATETIME, '20150319')),
        (CONVERT(DATETIME, '20150226 18:00'), CONVERT(DATETIME, '19760812')),
        (CONVERT(DATETIME, '20150305 07:47'), CONVERT(DATETIME, '19760812')),
        (CONVERT(DATETIME, '20150227 16:00'), CONVERT(DATETIME, '19760812'))
    ) x (START_DTTM , DTTM_OF_BIRTH);
```

Which gives:

```
START_DTTM              DTTM_OF_BIRTH           AGEGROUP
---------------------------------------------------------
2015-04-08 11:05        2015-03-19 00:00        " 1.C"
2015-05-05 10:35        2015-03-19 00:00        " 1.C"
2015-03-23 11:47        2015-03-19 00:00        " 1.C"
2015-03-25 14:35        2015-03-19 00:00        " 1.C"
2015-03-20 18:00        2015-03-19 00:00        " 1.C"
2015-02-26 18:00        1976-08-12 00:00        "2.A"
2015-03-05 07:47        1976-08-12 00:00        "2.A"
2015-02-27 16:00        1976-08-12 00:00        "2.A"
```